# Drawing a tile based Ellipse inside a Rectangle

Tags: java, math, ellipse

I'm trying to generate randomly sized ellipses and draw them to a map(just a 2D array of tiles). For the most part, it works, however it seems that when the room is wider than it is taller, it cuts off corners of the walls.

[image]

Below is my code for drawing the ellipse. Basically takes in a rectangle and draws the Ellipse inside of it.

```
private void AddCellEllipse(int xStart, int yStart, int xEnd, int yEnd, Tile tile)
{
    // Draw an ellipse centered in the passed-in coordinates
    float xCenter = (xEnd + xStart) / 2.0f;
    float yCenter = (yEnd + yStart) / 2.0f;
    float xAxis = (xEnd - xStart) / 2.0f;
    float yAxis = (yEnd - yStart) / 2.0f;

    for (int y = yStart; y <= yEnd; y++)
        for (int x = xStart; x <= xEnd; x++)
        {
            // Only draw if (x,y) is within the ellipse
            if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x - xCenter) / xAxis, 2.0) + Math.pow((y - yCenter) / yAxis, 2.0)) <= 1.0f)
                tiles[x][y] = tile;
        }
}
```

I call that method like so. Generates a randomly sized rectangle in a random position, then creates an ellipse of wall tiles, then covers the inside wall tiles with floor tiles.

```
    AddCellEllipse(xRoomStart, yRoomStart, xRoomStart + roomWidth, yRoomStart + roomHeight, Tile.WALL);
    AddCellEllipse(xRoomStart + 1, yRoomStart + 1, xRoomStart + roomWidth - 1, yRoomStart + roomHeight - 1, Tile.FLOOR);
```

Also bonus question, anyone have any idea how I can make it not put the 1 tile sticking out at the top/bottom of the ellipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Bresenham ellipse algorithm](https://sites.google.com/site/ruslancray/lab/projects/bresenhamscircleellipsedrawingalgorithm/bresenham-s-circle-ellipse-drawing-algorithm) or midpoint algorithm to draw ellipses.

And when you draw two symmetric points (tiles) with mentioned algo like these:

```
DrawPixel (xc + x, yc + y);
DrawPixel (xc - x, yc + y);
```

just fill line segment between them with interior tiles.

Comment: In that example of the Bresenham algorithm, I'm assuming the xc and yc variables are the center of the ellipse?

Comment: Yes, it is. Like your xCenter and yCenter

Comment: Thanks. I've managed to implement that algorithm, just have to make it fill in the ellipse with floor tiles now but I've generated a few maps and haven't noticed the issue again.